# Plotting datetime fields using chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I have managed to plot a scatter graph of some temperature values against sequence number, however now I want to replace the sequence number by a datetime field from my database.

I included moment.js in my directory, replaced the x value directly by the datetime field and formatted the xAxes for time.

```
{{-- Temperature Graph --}}
<script>
var ctx_temperature = document.getElementById('temperature').getContext('2d');
var temperature = new Chart(ctx_temperature, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [{ x: '2019-07-01 00:01:01', y: 100}, { x: '2019-07-01 00:12:01', y: 200 }],
            borderColor: '#191970',
            backgroundColor: '#191970',
            borderWidth: 2,
            pointBackgroundColor: '#d1d1e2',
            pointBorderColor: '#191970',
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            fill: false,
            showLine: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{ type: 'time', time: { unit: 'minute' }, distribution: 'series' }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question or stated a problem.

Comment: @timclutton The code above shows my attempt at trying to use datetime in the x-axis however it is not working. That is my problem.

Comment: You need to move the `unit` option to the `time` object, e.g., `xAxes: [{ type: 'time', time: { unit: 'minute' }, distribution: 'series' }]`. Otherwise please edit your question to include a valid dataset for testing (show us the values used for `x` and `y`).

Comment: Please elaborate on "however it is not working". The code you've posted works for me, when given a valid dataset (e.g. `data: [{ x: '2019-07-01 00:01:01', y: 100}, { x: '2019-07-01 00:12:01', y: 200 }]`). What *exactly* is the problem? Does the chart not display? Is there an error message?

Comment: @timclutton I changed the xAxes to as you specified. The datetime values are stored as 2019-07-17 12:40:57 (for example). I also tried replacing the x value to a fixed one such as x: '2019-07-01 00:01:01'. The chart does not display - on the chart.js documentation they specified to include the Moment.js which I also included.

Comment: Is there any error message in your web browsers console?

Comment: @timclutton - Thank you for your help, when not using the time in the xAxis I do not get any errors, but when using the above code (i.e. using time) I get the following errors: https://ibb.co/TPHS05z
https://ibb.co/JQLr6sX
https://ibb.co/q7MJfnG
https://ibb.co/k3jxwK5

Comment: @timclutton please see revised code in original post - that code does not load any chart for me. What am I missing?

Comment: "This method is not implemented" - this probably means you haven't included moment.js, or you haven't included it *before* Chart.js. Verify moment.js is loaded before Chart.js. Or just use `chart.bundle.js` which has moment.js built-in.

Comment: @timclutton that did the trick! I had to load moment.js before, thanks a lot!! Due to the large amount of data I am noting that the chart makes the webpage much slower when using time instead of a number for the xAxes - what could be causing this?

Comment: @timclutton sorry for the confusion, all is fine now! Thank you very much! :) Much appreciated